# Is this hadith about Byzantines authentic?

Tags: hadith, uloom-al-hadith

I came across the following hadith about the Byzantines on [this](https://www.abuaminaelias.com/dailyhadithonline/2013/06/12/romans-five-good-traits/) website:

> Al-Mustawrid reported: He said in front of Amr ibn al-‘As that he
> heard the Messenger of Allah, peace and blessings be upon him, say,
> “The Hour will be established while the Romans are the majority of
> people.” Amr said, “Be careful what you say.” He said, “I have said
> what I heard from the Messenger of Allah.” Amr said, “If the Prophet
> said that, indeed, there are four good qualities in them: they are the
> most forbearing of people in tribulation, they are the quickest to
> recover after a calamity, they are the most eager to return after a
> retreat, and they are good to the poor, the orphan, and the
> vulnerable. Their fifth quality is good and beautiful: they are the
> best at stopping the oppression of their kings.”
>
> Source: Ṣaḥīḥ Muslim 2898
>
> Grade: Sahih (authentic) according to Muslim

Can someone confirm the authenticity of this hadith?

Comment: The authenticity is literally given in your quote...

Comment: Please explain why you doubt the authenticity? What is the reason for your question?

Comment: @Medi1Saif AsSalam Aalykum. I did not see it mentioned elsewhere and only this website. Some ahadith are cited in multiple sources so it is easy to conclude that such ahadith are reliable.

Comment: Both Sahih al-Bukhari and Sahih Muslim are the most authentic hadith sources.

Comment: @TheZ AsSalam Aalykum. I understand. That being said, I expected this hadith to be found in other sources as well. IslamQA and IslamWeb, for example, are run by renowned Islamic scholars and have discussions on almost every matter and I expected to find this hadith there but I did not see it in those sources. Hence, I decided to double-check its authenticity.

Comment: IslamQA and IslamWeb are fatwa sites. It is not expected that they have a fatwa mentioning every hadith. You can refer to hadith sites like: https://sunnah.com/muslim:2898a

Comment: @TheZ JazakAllah Khair for the information.

Comment: this hadith is recorded in sahih muslim and there are two narrations ( 2898a and 2898b). there isn't any room in doubting the authenticity specially when the narration chain consists of great narrators like Al-laith bin Sa'd and Abdullah bin Wahb, both of whom have narrated more than 1200 ahadith in major hadith literature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it is worth pointing at the fact that this [hadith](https://sunnah.com/muslim:2898a) includes two parts:

- A part which we can regard as a hadith or a report of a statement from the prophet():

> “The Hour will be established while the Romans are the majority of people.”

- A part which is a report of the interpretation or comment of a sahabi() -'Amr ibn al-'Aas- on the above statement of our prophet():

> “If the Prophet said that, indeed, there are four good qualities in them: they are the most forbearing of people in tribulation, they are the quickest to recover after a calamity, they are the most eager to return after a retreat, and they are good to the poor, the orphan, and the vulnerable. Their fifth quality is good and beautiful: they are the best at stopping the oppression of their kings.”

As the statement of the prophet () doesn't contradict any verse in the qur'an nor any other more reliable hadith we can safely accept the content as authentic. As such a statement needs a certain divine revelation.

As for the chain of transmission imam Muslim has reported the hadith twice in his Sahih to show that it has further backup (see the second version [here](https://sunnah.com/muslim:2898b)).

The hadith can further be found in Musnad Ahmad (See #[18022 here](https://al-maktaba.org/book/25794/14511)), Musnad al-Bazzar (See #[3463 here](https://al-maktaba.org/book/12981/3828)) -who only mentioned the prophetic statement- and at-Tabarani's al-Kabir (See #[736](https://al-maktaba.org/book/1733/21444) here and #[737 here](https://al-maktaba.org/book/1733/21446) in both al-Mustawrid however answered 'Amr with another statement of the prophet()) all reported it via al-Mustwarid.

Comment: Jazak Allah Khair for the thorough answer.